# PHP imagick convert PDF to JPEG not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, ghostscript, imagick

I installed imagick and ghostscript on my Windows OS. I want to convert a PDF file to an image. The imagick is installed and displaying in the phpinfo but the PDF won't be converted to an image.

I've tried using the 'magick' keyword instead of convert. I also installed legacy utilities and used the 'convert' function all to no avail.

Here are my xampp and pc specs:

arch: x86, vc14, ts enabled, win. 8, gswin32

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], $pdfDirectory.$filename)) {

    //the path to the PDF file
    $pdfWithPath = $pdfDirectory.$filename;

    //add the desired extension to the thumbnail
    $thumb = $thumb.".jpg";

    //execute imageMagick's 'convert', setting the color space to RGB and size to 200px wide
    exec("convert \"{$pdfWithPath}[0]\" -colorspace RGB -geometry 100 $thumbDirectory$thumb");

    //show the image
    $thumbnail =  "<p><a href=\"$pdfWithPath\"><img src=\"pdfimage/$thumb\" alt=\"\" /></a></p>";
    $filename1 =  "<p><a href=\"$pdfWithPath\"> FILE </a></p>";
    //echo "$thumbnail";
    //echo "$filename";
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO files (thumb, department,  title, author, publisher, date_published,  isbn) VALUES ('$thumbnail' , '$dept',  '$filename', '$author', '$publisher', '$datepublished',  '$isbn')";
    $run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);`
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: If you are using `exec` you are not using the imagik PHP extension

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful diagnostic. You'll need to do enough digging and debugging to find, at the absolute least, a probable cause, an error message, or some kind of hint as to what's going wrong. You should also identify how far this code gets before malfunctioning.

Comment: Can you SSH to the server and run the `convert` command manually, to see whether it works there? It helps to put this in a separate string, so you can log it in your code. You also need to escape parameters that come from the user, otherwise you will be allowing the user to run shell commands on your server (like SQL injection that @tadman mentions).

Comment: I wonder if you have a `PATH` issue that prevents PHP from seeing this command.

Answer (score 0):

Add the imagick path to your user variable or select add path to environment variables while installing imagick